# Armature becomes deformed when exported from Blender into gltf format

Tags: armature, export, gltf

## Context

I'm currently trying to create a hand model with an armature for use within a game. Something I'm doing is leading to the armature becoming corrupted when exporting to glb format.

To try to eliminate sources for my mistakes I tried experimenting with a known good model. If that known good model is directly loaded into my application it looks correct and deforms correctly with the armature.

[image]

If I import* that glb into blender it again looks correct

[image]

But if I then export** that model back to gltf (.glb) format and load that into my application the hand is badly corrupted

[image]

It's hard to see in a still image but it is still vaguely handlike with clear fingers. Just very badly deformed.

The exact same thing happens when I create a hand and armature from scratch in blender so I think it's going wrong in the export not the import.

If I turn off any armature control in the application the mesh appears correct (but obviously doesn't move). Equally when the armature control is turned on the hand sort of follows the movements requested (bending the index figure at the right time) but within a corrupted overall shape

## Question

How should I export a mesh and armature into gltf format such that the armature behaves correctly.

## Notes

I do have skinning turned on in the export

[image]

Going through the import and export seems to misalign the armature from the mesh in the loading application, despite looking correct in blender. Could there be some advanced way of providing an offset in gltf that isn't well supported? Interestingly turning off the Transform > +Y up option changes the way the mesh and armature are misaligned (90 degrees wrong -> 180 degrees wrong)

[image]

*Import is done with File > Import > GLTF 2.0

** Export is done with File > Export > GLTF 2.0

Comment: Does your second export work if you import it back into Blender? Does it work with https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/?

Comment: @scurest is still seems to work but it is "different". The bones have moved from the armature to the pose, I've added a screen shot to the question. It also opens in the viewer BUT shows an interesting warning "Node with a skinned mesh is not root. Parent transforms will not affect a skinned mesh.". Not sure if that's the problem, feels suspicious at least. I also get a second warning "Image contains unsupported features like non-default colorspace information, non-square pixels, or animation."

Comment: The bones moving to pose just means you're in Pose mode. If it works in both those don't you think the issue is with your application instead? If you still think there's a problem with export, suggest [filing a bug](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues). I don't think there's enough info here to debug.

Comment: @scurest Hmm, I'm beginning to think there may indeed be an issue with my application (or I think the library I'm using). Possibly that it supports some subset of GLTF but not the whole standard and in my "known good" example that feature isn't used and in what is exported from blender it is. Loading up the mesh and some debug points for the armature in my application shows the armature rotated away from the mesh in the exported case. Equally playing with the "+Y up option" export option changes the way its wrong, which further suggests not the full standard is supported